# What is the most appropriate way to pass objects between modules in python?

Tags: python, object, import, module

I have to access an object in a module from another module:

module_1.py:

```
import module_2

class A():
    def __init__():
         do_sth()

class B():
    def __init__():
         do_sth()
         self.x = some_object()
         do_sth_else(x)

    def show():
        show_gui()

def start():
    y = B()
    y.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

module_2.py:

```
def run_it(arg):
    run_run_run()
```

I need `self.x` object from `module_1` so that I can pass it as an argument to `run_it()` function in `module_2`. Note that `module_1` also imports `module_2`.

Is there a conventional method to access objects in other modules?

Comment: Your code in module 1 won't even run on its own, so better worry about that before you try importing it.  There will be no `self` until you instantiate `B`, and each instance of `B` has its own `self`, so there is no single `self.x` to import.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler/interpreter get angry at the line `self.x=B()`?

Comment: OK, did a little correction

Answer (score 0):

Now with your corrections, it looks like you want something like this:

```
from module_1 import B

run_it(B().x)
```

Which raises a question: If `x` is the same for all objects of `B`, why not make it a class member instead of an instance member. Something like:

```
class B:
    x = some_object()

    def __init__(self):
         do_sth()
         do_sth_else(B.x)

    def show(self):
        show_gui()
```

And in the other module

```
run_it(B.x)
```

---

Addressing your comment: `y` is local to `start`. You will need to return it:

```
def start():
    y = B()
    y.show()
    return y
```

And then

```
run_it(start())
```

---

Also `y.show()` will fail horribly as `show` doesn't accept parameters and will get passed `y` as `self`.

Comment: Actually I want `y.x`

Comment: `y` is local to `start` and not accessible from the outside.

Comment: After your edit, don't you have to add `self` before `x = some_object()`?

Comment: @alwbtc No. Maybe you want to read some tutorial on python, especial about basic concepts as classes and objects.

Comment: Won't it create 2 GUI windows, because you run `start()` twice (one in module_1 and other in module_2)?

Comment: @alwbtc No gui will ever be shown, because `y.show()` will raise an error anyhow. See my edit.

Comment: @alwbtc You have a method `run` and a method `start`. You call start independently. Should it be `run` which calls `start` in the first place.